# Facebook Embed Behaves Strange

Tags: ajax, facebook, embed

I am working on a project which you can view several embed codes from Facebook, Twitter, Pinterest etc. I load the embed codes via ajax. But I am having issues with facebook embed code. Facebook has a very messed up embed system. A regular embed code is consist of 2 parts; the script part and the embed part.

The Script Part

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) { var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; if (d.getElementById(id)) return; js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

The Embed part

```
<div class="fb-post" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=667590506599208&amp;set=a.155534741138123.32906.153667584658172&amp;type=1" data-width="550">
<div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=667590506599208&amp;set=a.155534741138123.32906.153667584658172&amp;type=1">Post</a> by <a href="https://www.facebook.com/cumhuriyetgzt">Cumhuriyet Gazetesi</a>.
</div>
</div>
```

I include the script part between the head tags. As I said, I load the embed codes via ajax, and when I do, I also load this

```
<script type="text/javascript"> FB.XFBML.parse(); </script>
```

code so that facebook embeds can reparse. The problem I have is; on the page load facebook embed codes does not work (even though they are loaded with ajax). When I reload the embed codes (reload button that triggers ajax load), then they work. Sometimes they don't work when there is twitter or pinterest embed codes on the same page.

Anyone has an idea what could be going on ? Where and how should I include the scripts and reparse code ?

Thanks

Edit: I am thinking the problem could be about the load order. So if the scripts load after the DOM element is loaded, than it wouldn't affect the embed code. Maybe if I make sure that I load the scripts BEFORE the page is loaded, it will work. Just an idea...

Answer (score 0):

Add below FB javascript anywhere in your javascript file.

```
(function(d, s, id) { var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; if (d.getElementById(id)) return; js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

And then

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

            FB.XFBML.parse();
          }
```

Call above function 2 or 3 seconds after the FB embedded content is loaded.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    if (typeof(FB) != 'undefined') {

       window.fbAsyncInit();

        } 
       }, 2000)
```

Comment: You shouldn't rely upon a timeout - you don't know how long the network is going to take to load the SDK. Use the built in events